# sync_to_async decorator, async view in Django

Tags: django, asynchronous

I am trying to follow the video tutorial and try to understand async view and @sync_to_async decorator in django.

I have this code:

```
import time
import asyncio

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.http import HttpResponse

from movies.models import Movie
from stories.models import Story



@sync_to_async
def get_movies_async():
    print('prepare to get the movies...')
    time.sleep(2)
    qs = Movie.objects.all()
    print('got all the movies')


@sync_to_async
def get_stories_async():
    print('prepare to get the stories...')
    time.sleep(5)
    qs = Story.objects.all()
    print('got all the stories')



async def main_view_async(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(get_movies_async(), get_stories_async())
    total = (time.time() - start_time)
    print("total: ", total)
    return HttpResponse('async!')
```

But when I call **main_view_async** from my browser it still takes 7 seconds, not 5 seconds like in the video tutorial.
The tutorial might be outdated (year 2020). Or perhaps I am doing something wrong? Can you please help?

**My output**

```
prepare to get the movies...
got all the movies
prepare to get the stories...
got all the stories
total:  7.0126471519470215
```

**The tutorial terminal output**

```
prepare to get the movies...
prepare to get the stories...
got all the movies
got all the stories
total:  5.0126471519470215
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it *is* because the tutorial is old.  As you can see in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/#sync-to-async), at the end of 2020 `asgiref` changed:

> asgiref version 3.3.0 changed the default value of the
> thread_sensitive parameter to True. This is a safer default, and in
> many cases interacting with Django the correct value, but be sure to
> evaluate uses of sync_to_async() if updating asgiref from a prior
> version.

This default `thread_sensitive` value can be changed to `False`, however, I do not know how to do that using the `@sync_to_async` decorator, but it *can* be done this way:

```py
# Change the function to a regular synchronous function
# Removed the decorator and
# Changed the name to make it obvious it's not async function
# @sync_to_async
def get_movies():
    print('prepare to get the movies...')
    time.sleep(2)
    qs = Movie.objects.all()
    print('got all the movies')

# Do the same to this function as what was done to the above function
# @sync_to_async
def get_stories():
    print('prepare to get the stories...')
    time.sleep(5)
    qs = Story.objects.all()
    print('got all the stories')


async def main_view_async(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Create async functions from the synchronous functions
    # Set the thread_sensitive to False
    get_movies_async = sync_to_async(get_movies, thread_sensitive=False)
    get_stories_async = sync_to_async(get_stories, thread_sensitive=False)

    await asyncio.gather(get_movies_async(), get_stories_async())
    total = (time.time() - start_time)
    print("total: ", total)
    return HttpResponse('async!')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @raphael is correct in identifying a change in the default behavior of `asgiref` version `3.3.0`, another approach to address the issue is by transforming your synchronous functions into fully asynchronous ones. Here's a modified implementation:

```py
async def get_movies_async():
    print('prepare to get the movies...')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    qs = [movie async for movie in Movie.objects.all()]
    print(qs)
    print('got all the movies!')

async def get_stories_async():
    print('prepare to get the stories...')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    qs = [story async for story in Story.objects.all()]
    print(qs)
    print('got all the stories!')

async def main_view_async(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(
        get_movies_async(),
        get_stories_async(),
    )
    total = (time.time() - start_time)
    print("total: ", total)
    return HttpResponse('async!')
```